# List of months and days in each month - divided into separate div's

Tags: php

I'm trying to get list of months and days for each month f.e.

```
January
01 02 03 04 05 (...)
February 
01 02 03 04 05 (...)
```

I'd love to have each month wrapped with div, which would have a css class.

How can I achive this? I've tried with code below, but it returns the list of days, without dividing them into separate months :/

```
$start_date = '2015-01-01';
$start_day = date('z', strtotime($start_date));
$days_in_a_year = date('z', strtotime('2015-12-31'));

$number_of_days = ($days_in_a_year - $start_day) +1 ;
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_days; $i++) {
    $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date)) . " +$i day");
    echo date('d-m-y F - l', $date) .'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cal_days_in_month()` function:

```
$year = 2015;

for($month=1; $month<=12; $month++){
    // Show month name
    $monthName = date('F', strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));
    echo "<div>$monthName: ";

    // Calculate days in given month
    $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

    // Print days
    for($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++)
    { echo "$i "; }

    // Close div
    echo '</div>';
}
```

EDIT: Solution without extra array.

Comment: Thank you :)

Works like a charm, I've tweaked it a little bit to add css class with specified month number

`echo '<div class="miesiac-'; echo $key; echo '"><h2>'.$month.'</h2>: ';` so it returns the divs with class: `<div class="miesiac-1">(...)</div>` :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should iterate through months first and then iterate through days inside the inner loop. Something like this:

```
$year = '2015';

for($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
    $month_name = date('F', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-01'));
    echo '<div class="month-wrap">';
    echo $month_name;
    $days_in_month = date('t', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-01'));

    for($day = 1; $day <= $days_in_month; $day++)
    {
        echo '<div class="day-wrap">' . $day . '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```